# Let$ f ∈ L[a, b]$ and $\{A_k\}$ be a countable collection of pairwise disjoint measurable subsets of $[a, b]$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f ∈ L[a, b]$ and $\{A_k\}$ be a countable collection of pairwise
disjoint measurable subsets of $[a, b]$. Explain why the
statement

$$\int_{\bigcup_k A_k}f = \sum_k \int_{A_k}f$$
involves interchanging limit operations. Then prove it is true.

I'm going through my textbook and came across this question however I can not find anything that related to interchanging limit operations in the book. How does one go about this question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's some guide to [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Yes we have studied that

Answer (score 1):

It involves interchanging limits in the following way:

$$\sum_k\int_{A_k}f=\sum_k\int_{[a,b]} 1_{A_k}f = \int_{[a,b]}\sum_k 1_{A_k}f$$
Here $1_A(x)=1$ if and only if $x\in A$. Since the sum has infinitely many summands, you interchange an integral with another limit process by interchanging the sum and the integral.
Now please note that $\sum_k 1_{A_k}=1_{\cup_k A_k}$, since the $A_k$ are pairwise disjoint. Hence
$$\int_{[a,b]}\sum_k 1_{A_k}f=\int_{\cup_k A_k}f.$$

A possible proof would be by the dominated convergence theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) since your $f$ is integrable and the $A_k$ are pairwise disjoint. You can work out the details as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

In the LHS we can recognize: $$\int\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf\chi_{A_k}$$

In the RHS we can recognize: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\int f\chi_{A_k}$$

Defining $s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nf\chi_{A_k}$ we have $\int s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\int f\chi_{A_k}$ so then the statement is:$$\int\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int s_n$$ 
There are several theorems that state conditions under which this is indeed true.

Answer (score 0):

Set $B_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k,\ A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ and $f_n=\chi_{B_n}\cdot f$. Then $f_n\to f\cdot \chi_A$ and $|f_n|\le |f|$ and so since $f\in L^1([a,b])$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem applies and we have

$\lim\int_{a}^{b}f_n=\int_{a}^{b}\lim f_n\Rightarrow \lim\int_{a}^{b}\chi_{B_n}\cdot f=\int_{a}^{b}f\cdot \chi_A\ \Rightarrow $

$\lim\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{a}^{b}\chi_{A_k}\cdot f=\int_Af\Rightarrow \lim\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{A_k}f=\int_Af.$